# How to prevent PHP namespace conflicts (pre-bundled packages)

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, version, conflict

Let's assume we have a PHP project with dependencies **A** and **B** each depending on PHP library **X**, but in a different version.

Usually, one would use a PHP dependency manager such as composer which would either resolve this conflict by including **X** in a version compatible to both **A** and **B** or display an error if the conflict cannot be resolved.

Now, many PHP applications allow their users to install plugins simply by uploading pre-bundled packages and extracting them to a specific plugin directory.

If **A** and **B** were such pre-bundled plugins and both would bring their own version of library **X**, we might run into problems since no dependency manager is available to select a compatible **X** for us or display an error in case there is none.

To prevent any such conflicts caused by the inability of PHP to have library **X** being loaded twice with different version into the same namespace, we could put **A**'s **X** and **B**'s **X** into different namespaces (which might be hard to do automatically as we would need a PHP parser for that...).

My question is:

- How would you solve this problem? Can you recommend this approach or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no solution without changing the code. If two versions of ´\Vendor\AnyClass´ do exist in the filesystem, and code is executed to use them both, either an error appears because redeclaring that class is not allowed, or because the expected class is incompatible. It will only work if the interface of the class is implemented the same, i.e. the two codes are compatible. The problem of compatibility is complicated if it isn't only that one class, but an entire tree of objects that may react badly to mixing classes from different versions, even though they offer a compatible interface.

Changing the namespace is changing the code. Who's responsible for that? I can think of some automatic code parser that would be able to add a specific namespace prefix for each plugin, but that task hasn't been done to my knowledge in PHP. The Java guys in my company made some remarks that such a problem has been solved there, but I have no details.

Also, it doubles your code base, and the duplicated code has to share only the one opcode cache you have.

I know that the core developers of Wordpress are still struggling with this problem. There are some coded suggestions of how to use Composer for dependency management (i.e. plugins and their dependencies), but I don't think they made enough progress for now.

Essentially you have two choices: 1. Create a code namespace prefixer, parse all the files belonging to a plugin (so the plugin author has to include his dependencies somehow), change the code, live with the code duplication, and see what awaits you when it comes to debugging. The downside is that no code outside of that plugin will be easily able to use the plugin code directly because that would mean to know the created prefix. 2. Implement some form of dependency management, preferably using Composer, and don't change the namespaces.

**Update:** I consulted my Java co-workers again, and they basically made the same statement about Java that I made about PHP: You cannot have two different versions of a class under the same class name, and there is no "magic" even for Java but renaming the class to a different namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your input! You are essentially confirming my thoughts - that there is no alternative to changing the namespace of the dependency. What do you mean with "implement some form of dep. management"? As stated in my question, composer is no option since the plugins have to 'run out of the box' after being uploaded to the server.

Comment: By saying "implement some form of dep. management" I was suggesting that your plugin uploads could state their dependencies just like Composer, and you could try to at least detect any conflicts and work something out. However, implementing the same thing that Composer already does is insane, so it may be wise to use Composer components help you with that task. You could also force any plugin to only use exactly one namespace, enforcing it by checking all files. Problem solved. Any plugin would have to include dependencies anyway, they cannot rely on anything.

Comment: There are actually several alternatives to **prefix** and change the scopes (namespaces) of PHP files and automatically update Composer dependencies and your codebase. For more info, check this answer: [3rd party dependency conflict in developing Wordpress Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144816/3rd-party-dependency-conflict-in-developing-wordpress-plugin)

Comment: @AnibalSanchez Funny that the answers in the link you gave are all talking about prefixing the PHP code. Which alternatives are you referring to?

Comment: @sven I think that the English expression that I used is not right or it is confusing... I meant that "There are several available tools that can be used to update Composer dependencies and your codebase..."