# Is there a tool that maps out a composer dependency tree?

Tags: php, composer-php

There is an existing problem with composer-php described in this question:

[How to prevent PHP namespace conflicts (pre-bundled packages)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358490/how-to-prevent-php-namespace-conflicts-pre-bundled-packages)

In a nutshell, suppose we have an application **MyApp**, which depends on two third party libraries, **Foo v1** and **Bar v1**. These two libraries in turn both depend on the library **Baz v1**. We want to upgrade to **Bar v2**, but it depends on **Baz v2**, which has backwards incompatible changes, and will hence break **Foo v1**.

---

Are there any tools that you can point to a `composer.json` file, which will tell you what co-dependencies there are, or (ideally) graphically display a tree of dependencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a more recently added (March 2021) library that uses the D3JS 'Collapsible tree' visualization: https://github.com/markfullmer/dependency_tree

[image]

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/clue/graph-composer generates dependency graphs from composer.json files and outputs them in e.g. svg.