# Wrong class being called

Tags: php, wordpress, jwt, namespaces

I have a weird problem occurring with my code.

I am currently working on a WordPress project, where there are a whole load of plugins involved, but the main one I am concerned with is the [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) because I am using it to implement REST API authentication.

Everything works great when one sends the login credentials to the endpoint `/jwt-auth/v1/token`, because a token and some user information is returned.

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:12345/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "username": "hello@example.com",
    "password": "password"
}'
```

The problem comes when one tries to validate the token sent, by calling the endpoint `/jwt-auth/v1/token/validate`

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:12345/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/validate \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer {{ token }}'
```

I get a response with a `403` status code and the following response

```
{
    "code": "jwt_auth_invalid_token",
    "message": "Algorithm not allowed",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

After doing some investigation, I realized I have two plugins using a similar library and here they are

```bash
plugins
├── jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api
│   └── vendor # not exactly like this, but close enough
├── the-events-calendar
│   └── vendor
```

And here is the class and method responsible for validating the token

```php
<?php

/** Require the JWT library. */
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;

class Jwt_Auth_Public
{
    ...

    /**
     * Main validation function, this function try to get the Authentication
     * headers and decoded.
     *
     * @param bool $output
     *
     * @return WP_Error | Object | Array
     */
    public function validate_token($output = true)
    {
        ...

        /** Try to decode the token */
        try {
            header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
            $jwt = new ReflectionClass(JWT::class);
            var_dump($token, $jwt->getFileName()); exit;
            $token = JWT::decode(
                $token,
                new Key($secret_key, apply_filters('jwt_auth_algorithm', 'HS256'))
            );
            
            ...
            
            /** If the output is true return an answer to the request to show it */
            return array(
                'code' => 'jwt_auth_valid_token',
                'data' => array(
                    'status' => 200,
                ),
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            /** Something is wrong trying to decode the token, send back the error */
            return new WP_Error(
                'jwt_auth_invalid_token',
                $e->getMessage(),
                array(
                    'status' => 403,
                )
            );
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

You will notice I have added a few lines below to the method to try and debug what is causing this issue

```php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$jwt = new ReflectionClass(JWT::class);
var_dump($token, $jwt->getFileName()); exit;
```

And the output is

```
string(260) "{{ token }}" 
string(89) "/var/www/hello-world/public_html/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/common/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php"
```

Instead of something like this

```
string(260) "{{ token }}"
string(131) "/var/www/hello-world/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/includes/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php"
```

So I was wondering what can one do to resolve something like this?

Comment: You can't really do much except forking one plugin and prefixing vendor dependencies. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144816/3rd-party-dependency-conflict-in-developing-wordpress-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same bug with a 403 error "algorithm not allowed"

In the plugin folder, you need to modify the `public > class-jwt-auth-public.php` file.

From line 281 before modification :

```
        /** Try to decode the token */
    try {
        $token = JWT::decode(
            $token,
            new Key($secret_key, apply_filters('jwt_auth_algorithm', 'HS256'))
        );
```

From line 281 after modification :

```
        /** Try to decode the token */
    try {
        $token = JWT::decode(
            $token,
            $secret_key, 
            array_keys(JWT::$supported_algs)
        );
```

It's not the cleanest solution because you're basically allowing all JWT algorithm, but every other solution didn't work for me !

I hope it's what you were looking for :)