Handling multiple composer vendor directories and autoload with WordPress themes and plugins
I am working on a WordPress theme that uses Composer to include various dependencies. The vendor directory is bundled with the theme and the autoload file is included in the theme's functions file. There have been no problems with this set up.
Now I am working on a plugin that uses Composer to include various dependencies of its own. My initial approach was to copy what I did for the theme and include the autoload file in the plugin. This works if the plugin is installed manually and there are no conflicts between the theme and the plugin's dependencies, but that is not always guaranteed.
I would like to keep both the theme and the plugin's dependencies independent of each other if possible. That way I can use the theme with or without the plugin and vice versa without causing any pathing or autoload issues.
I am also using Composer to manage plugin installations with WordPress. Currently the theme requires my plugin through composer.json and it automatically downloads and installs the plugin into the WordPress plugin directory. This also installs the plugin's dependencies into the theme's vendor directory which I do not want.
{
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": "theme/vendor",
    "allow-plugins": {
      "composer/installers": true
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "my-company/custom-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    ...
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git@bitbucket.org:my-company/custom-plugin.git"
    },
   ...
  ]
}


Is it possible to force a dependency to use its own vendor-dir setting? Or is there a better way to handle this situation?
Essentially I want to maintain the ability to install the plugin manually via zip upload (its vendor dir bundled in the zip is the only way I can think of to accomplish this), or install it via composer but prevent composer from automatically installing the plugin's dependencies in the root vendor dir.
This is the composer.json of my plugin:
{
  "name": "my-company/custom-plugin",
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/my-company/custom-plugin",
  "type": "wordpress-plugin",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=8.0",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "3.4.0.0" <--- this is installed to the theme's vendor dir
  },
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": "./plugin-specific-vendor" <--- this does not work
  }
}



Or even more similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144816/3rd-party-dependency-conflict-in-developing-wordpress-plugin
